# Adjust height of UITableViewCell to height of UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I got two cells in my `UITableView`. One is a custom `UITableViewCell` and the other is a cell with a `UITextView` inside and called the type `TextViewCell`.

Because they are static I the cells are loaded in `viewDidLoad` method from a xib:

```
textCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: TextViewCell.self),
                                        owner: self, options: nil)?.first! as! TextViewCell
ratingCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: RatingCell.self),
                                          owner: self, options: nil)?.first! as! RatingCell
```

Now I try to change the height with the the `heightForRowAt` delegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        return textCell.textView.contentSize.height
    }
    return ratingCell.ratingView.frame.height
}
```

I disabled scrolling on the `UITextView` but the cell is not resizing properly. In fact the cells gets smaller. 
The constraints of the `TextViewCell` look like this:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: is this the only content your textView have?

Comment: The UITextView doesn't have a fixed height, so will be defaulting to the height of 1 line of text. Try adding a height constraint to the UITextView

Comment: I would suggest looking into self sizing UITableViewCells.  Here are a couple of links to help https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html  and https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use self-sizing `UITableViewCell`. Replace your current implementation of `heightForRowAt` with the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Now height of cells in your `UITableView` object will be calculated automatically based on constraints.
Also, add some estimated value for row height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 100.0 // You can set any other value, it's up to you
}
```

Now you will see that the `UITextView` view fills the whole `UITableViewCell` cell.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the height of UITextView in heightForRowAt and return this height as cell height. See example below

```
        let lblDescLong = UITextView()
        lblDescLong.textAlignment = .left
        lblDescLong.text = “your text for text view”
        lblDescLong.font = YourFont(size: 12)
        let newSize = lblDescLong.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: widthForTextView, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        return newSize.height
```